# How to update WordPress SQL DB on MAMP OS x localhost

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

Any help appreciated.

I have a working WordPress site and an (old) copy of it running on MAMP on Mac OS X. To keep the dev site in sync, I need to 'update' / replace the old sql DB on MAMP with a copy of the one on the live site. I've read a lot of websites but cannot find this question exactly addressed and cannot figure out how to do this.

I'm a relative beginner to MAMP and WordPress but got it working six months back and just can't figure out now how to get the two in sync again.

Comment: I guess you should ask in wordpress forum

Comment: Apologies. I got a bit lost somewhere!